# Writing code in R markdown but suppressing calculations

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I want to create a pdf document using rstudio, knitr. I would like to present code used to obtain results. The problem is that when creating a pdf, everything is calculated. That usually wouldn't be the problem, but I have really complex models on a huge data set, and it takes hours to complete.

Is there a way of presenting code that will not get calculated? For the presentation of the results, I could load the data from calculations I already made.

If I run the calculations for creating pdf, every time I wanted to make a change I would have to do the calculations over and over again.

Comment: Thank you. Please instead of a comment, give an answer so I can give you credit, and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `knitr` option `eval` to suppress evaluation of the R code but still output and format the R code. e.g.

````
```{r eval=FALSE}
summary(cars)
```
````